# Add two IQueryables (int/decimal) in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, decimal, iqueryable

I am pulling two values from a MYSQL database. I have one int and one decimal...how do I add them?

Currently, my code is:

```
orderTotal += cartItem.Count * storeDB.Designs.Select(p => p.Price);

// countItem.Count = int
// storeDB.select = decimal
```

How do I add these? I've tried type casting every which way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: edited to correct `code` layout and grammatical style.

Comment: @user498351 welcome to StackOverflow, hope you find it to your liking.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on here. Please show us what the tables look like, give us some sample data, and what output you're looking for.

Comment: Why do you have variables called `int`, `select` and `decimal`? This is very confusing! Are those actually variables or are you describing the type information? I guess the latter...

Comment: @Stu ~ You have to mark all the lines as code, not just the first one :p

Comment: @drachenstern: what language would the last two lines be in?

Comment: @stu it's not syntax but it's supposed to convey meaning. Letting it all run together blocked the usefulness it would impart later. He's telling us that `countItem.Count` is an int, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `storeDB.Designs.Select(p => p.Price)` is not a decimal. It is an `IEnumerable<decimal>`. Your logic should look something like this:

```
 orderTotal += cartItem.Count * 
               storeDb.Designs.First(d => d.Id == cartItem.Id).Price;
```

Keep in mind that `First` will throw if there is not an item in the database with the right id ( `cartItem.Id`).

Comment: Not if Price is a decimal. It would be an IQueryable<decimal>. The Select method is a projection. ^ Stealth edited.

Comment: @Dismissile, yeah I noticed and fixed it before anyone noticed (or so I thought ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`.Select()` returns a collection, which can't be cast to the operand of a multiplication, even if it only contains one item. Take a look at [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) and its kin, which return scalars.

If you're *expecting* more than one value, you'll need to aggregate `Designs` with something like [`Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) before multiplying the result.